# Can You Minimize the Soft Keyboard on Android From Text Completed Event

Tags: maui

I've seen various answers to this question for older versions but not sure how to translate to MAUI.  The question being, is there a way that you can minimize the soft keyboard on a device from the Text Completed event of an Entry control?

Comment: Can you give a link to one of the older xamarin answers?

Comment: This is the one I was first looking at:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42864096/how-to-hide-softkeyboard-in-xamarin-android-programmatically#:~:text=this%20code%20for%20hide%20soft%20keyboard%20in%20fragment,and%20in%20Activity%20you%20can%20use%20this%20code%3A.  I also found this one but also haven't really figured out how to translate it:  https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/12559/how-to-hide-the-keyboard-when-scrolling-in-xamarin-forms-listview-sflistview.

Answer (score 5):

I finally figured out how to do this.  This solution is for Android only right now.  It doesn't use a custom handler since I could not get the window token from PlatformView.  Instead the code looks like this:

```
#if ANDROID
            var imm = (Android.Views.InputMethods.InputMethodManager)MauiApplication.Current.GetSystemService(Android.Content.Context.InputMethodService);

            if (imm != null)
            {
                //this stuff came from here:  https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/12559/how-to-hide-the-keyboard-when-scrolling-in-xamarin-forms-listview-sflistview
                var activity = Microsoft.Maui.ApplicationModel.Platform.CurrentActivity;
                Android.OS.IBinder wToken = activity.CurrentFocus?.WindowToken;
                imm.HideSoftInputFromWindow(wToken, 0);
            }
#endif
```

So credit to the syncfusion folks that published their version, and this code above is modified from that to work in MAUI.

Comment: Good - that is better anyway, because it isn't dependent on the type of PlatformView. So can call from anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

The code belongs in a custom handler. Based on [Customize a control with a mapper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/handlers/customize#customize-a-control-with-a-mapper).

In that Maui handler, `handler.PlatformView` is the Android control. Xamarin.Android properties/methods would be on that.

Something like:

```cs
using Microsoft.Maui.Platform;

namespace CustomizeHandlersDemo;

public partial class CustomizeEntryPage : ContentPage
{
    public CustomizeEntryPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ModifyEntry();
    }

    void ModifyEntry()
    {
        Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.EntryHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping(
"MyCustomization", (handler, view) =>
        {
#if ANDROID
        handler.PlatformView....
#elif IOS
#elif WINDOWS
#endif
        });
    }
}
```

NOTE: That example modifies ALL Entries.

---

If you want to modify only SOME Entries, you instead define a subclass (e.g. `public class MyEntry : Entry {}`), and do this:

```cs
Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.EntryHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping(
"MyEntryCustomizationOrWhatever", (handler, view) =>
{
    if (view is MyEntry)
    {
#if ANDROID
        handler.PlatformView....
#elif IOS
#elif WINDOWS
#endif
    }
});
```

---

For your specific situation, the line you were having trouble adapting to Maui contains `btnSignIn.WindowToken`.

Replace that with `handler.PlatformView.WindowToken`.

Comment: Thank you for that, but I am having a problem with handler.PlatformView.WindowToken - it is always null.  I've tried calling ModifyEntry from the constructor as you've shown above, as well as from the OnNavigatedTo override, but it is always null.  I looked at it in the debugger and it doesn't even show a WindowToken property on PlatformView, so not sure how else to dig into this?